# How to get facebook,gmail sites on a iframe and on a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, facebook

I want to use facebook page and gmail and such social media pages on iframes and tabs. How can I do that ?

Some pages can be loaded and somepages like facebook and gmail cannot.

This is my try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>iframes</h1>
  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe> 
  <iframe src="http://www.gmail.com"></iframe> 
  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe> 

  <br>

  <h1>divs</h1>


  <div> 
        <object type="text/html" data="http://www.facebook.com" width="300px" height="300px" style="overflow:auto;float:left;border:5px ridge blue">
        </object>
  </div>

  <div> 
        <object type="text/html" data="http://www.w3schools.com" width="300px" height="300px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
        </object>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s impossible, X-Frame-Options in the HTTP response - forbids it.

But if you do a simple proxy at the server - which will load them via file_get_contents and give - the show from you website - turn

Comment: Can you please explain about proxy server thing ?

Comment: something like that: proxy.php get url as param, then file_get_contents with it and return data.